# C conflicting type bug

Tags: c

When I try to compile this I'm being told by gcc that I have conflicting types for `pack_cui(C)`.

I don't see how I could be getting conflicting types as I know I'm passing in a `char*`.  I'm new to C so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

```
int main(){
  char* C = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
  C[0] = 1;
  C[1] = 2;
  C[2] = -1;
  C[3] = 4;
  pack_cui(C);
  return 0;
}

unsigned int pack_cui(char* C){
  unsigned int new_int = 0;
  unsigned int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    new_int = new_int | (unsigned int)(signed int)C[i];
    if(i != 3) new_int = new_int << 8;
  }
  return new_int;
}
```

The error I received was

```
hw12.c:17:14: error: conflicting types for ‘pack_cui’
 unsigned int pack_cui(char* C){
              ^
hw12.c:13:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘pack_cui’ was here
     pack_cui(C);
```

Comment: Show complete, reproducible code.

Comment: "Conflicting types" could just mean you are *declaring* the function somewhere else, with a different declaration.

Comment: Please update the question to show a complete program that reproduces the problem *and* the exact copy-and-pasted error message you got from gcc.

Comment: Make sure there is a prototype for `pack_cui()` available for `main()`.

Comment: `(unsigned int)(signed int)` should be `(unsigned char)`

Comment: I just noticed that! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add a prototype for `pack_cui` before `main`:

```
unsigned int pack_cui(char* C);
```

Otherwise, when the compiler sees the call to `pack_cui`, it has to guess the type, and in this case it guesses wrong.

Comment: This worked, thank you.  I figured that since it knew the function existed below it that it would also know the type of that function.

Comment: @user1679198: The compiler *doesn't* know the function exists. If you declare the function but never define it, you'll get an error at link time.

Comment: ".. it has to guess the type" - well, actually it always 'guesses' both returned type and all parameters are `int`. It's somewhere in the specifications.

Comment: @user1679198 The compiler reads your code from top to bottom, and never goes back to look at something again. (That's because C was made when there wasn't enough memory to do that)

Answer (score 2):

When you call an undeclared function, the C89 standard mandates an implicit declaration. This declaration would be:

```
int pack_cui();
```

The `()` is not the same as `(void)`, it indicates that the function takes an *unspecified* number of arguments, whereas `(void)` means zero. This is left over from pre-ISO/ANSI C, back in the K&R days.

You don't want that, because that is the wrong declaration. Create your own declaration at the top, above `main()`:

```
unsigned pack_cui(char *);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call a C function, whether it's one of your own or one declared by the standard library, you must have a visible declaration of that function so the compiler knows how to generate the code to call it. That declaration *should* be a prototype, i.e., a declaration that specifies the types of the function's parameters. A function *definition* (with the `{` ... `}` containing the code that implements the function) provide a declaration.

In your example, no declaration of `pack_cui` is visible at the point of the call; it's not defined until later.

You can fix this by moving the definition of `pack_cui` above the definition of `main`, *or* by adding a "forward declaration" and leaving the definitions where they are.

The latter would look like this:

```
unsigned int pack_cui(char* C);   /* a declaration, not a definition */

int main(void) {                  /* definition of main */
    /* ... */
}

unsigned int pack_cui(char* C) {  /* definition of pack_cui */
    /* ... */
}
```

Either approach is acceptable.

For much the same reason, you need to provide a declaration for the `malloc` function.  You should do this by adding

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to the top of your source file.

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition of `pack_cui` from below the `main` function, to above the `main` function. Or set up and include a header file that declares `pack_cui`.

Also, once this is done, recompile with warnings enabled, so that you catch the other issue with your code:

```
$ gcc -Wall foo.c
```

You should include `stdlib.h`, at least.

Comment: Ok great, that was my problem.  I actually have stdlib.h included at the top, I just didn't mention it in my post, probably should have.  I just compiled with  -Wall as per your suggestion but it didn't catch any other issue or am I missing something?  I know that I am leaking memory here but I wasn't too worried about that.