# Conflicting type C

Tags: c, types

I'm having some problem with a conflicting type that I don't understand. I want to change a date previously set but it's giving me a headache.

```
int main(){
float any=11;
llegirany(&any);
printf("%f",any);
getch();    
}

void llegirany(float * any){    
float auxi; 
auxi=llegirinterval(1,31);  
*any= auxi;
}

float llegirinterval(float n1,float n2){
float aux;
       do{          
            scanf("%f",&aux);
        }while(aux>n2 || aux<n1);
return aux;
}
```

And I get this output error:

> 65    7   D:\DAM\PRo\pruebaconio.c    [Error] conflicting types for
>   'llegirinterval' 62   7   D:\DAM\PRo\pruebaconio.c    [Note] previous
>   implicit declaration of 'llegirinterval' was here

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009277/c-conflicting-type-bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the function `llegirinterval` before *declaring* it.

You should move the *definition* of `llegirinterval` before the *definition* of `llegirany` or at least *declare* `llegirinterval` before it's used.

Check the [difference between definition and declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

EDITED following @Olaf comment.

Comment: Indeed, no function prototypes, and no `#include` files.

Comment: Using a function before its _definition_ is fine. But you need its _declaration_.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a declaration to the function *llegirinterval()* before you use it. You should also declare other functions contained in the code as well:

```
void llegirany(float *any);
float llegirinterval(float n1,float n2);

int main(){
    float any=11;

...

void llegirany(float * any){
    float auxi;
    auxi=llegirinterval(1,31);
    *any= auxi;
}
```

By default, C considers the type of any variable name that has not been explicitly typed yet as *int*. So, when it sees the call to:

```
llegirany(&any);
```

in the third line of main, the compiler says "aha, a function named *llegirany* that returns an *int*.

Later on, when the compiler gets to the actual function definition for the function, it gets confused -- wait, I thought that *llegirany* returns an *int*, and now you tell me it returns a *float*.

Comment: You should add *both* function prototypes before `main()`, since `main()` calls one which calls the other. In the source code each is below the one that calls it.

Comment: @Weather Vane -- Correct.